# having problem in a fragment view (View Root) in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rootview

'''
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root   =inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)
    return root;
}
```

}
'''

fragment_home created but not being recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Try once-

```
  import packagename.R //import should be like this use your project package name 
    
           public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
            
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View root   =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)**//Here must use R of project not a android default**
                return root;
            }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks bro this worked fine.  The key was to import R and to add just R.layout.fragment_home,container,false              and that worked. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

could you please be more specific about your issue
is the fragment not showing on the screen?
or you want the naveController to recognize it and navigate to it in a certain action

remove the android directory and call R.layout.fragment_layout

```
 View root   =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)
return root;
```

Comment: Thanks bro this worked after importing R    "in this case R would be android object or the object created by us" ?